# Issue with Keycloak Multi tenancy

Tags: java, tomcat, keycloak

I am stuck in Keycloak authentication of multi tenancy.

I have configured PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver in my package: com.demo.util.

The context param has been set on web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
        <param-name>keycloak.config.resolver</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.util.PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I deployed the application on Tomcat. I have registered the context.xml in meta-inf with the required adapter.

Tomcat lib directory has all the required keycloak jar files.

But PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver never gets called on any request to the url. PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver should get called on any call to the url. The only time it calls if I remove the Maven dependency from the deployment assemply of Eclipse. But this cannot be the way to achieve this.

### Sample of pathresolver:

```
public class PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {

    private final Map<String, KeycloakDeployment> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, KeycloakDeployment>();

    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request request) {
        System.out.println("**********I am called***************");
}}
```

### pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.keycloak.example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer-portal-example</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
<!--    <name>Customer Portal - Secured via Valve</name> -->
    <description />


    <name>talent-biz-layer</name>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

     <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/java/main</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: please share your `web.xml` file too

Answer (score 1):

So you have the keycloak jar files in the tomcat lib directory **and** your war file? That will cause a conflict because your code will have its own version of the `KeycloakConfigResolver` interface (from your war file) which is not the same as the version used by keycloak (that comes from the tomcat lib directory). So your class is not implementing the keycloak version of the interface and not called because of that.

Solution: Use `<scope>provided</scope>` for all the jars that are in tomcat lib directory; this way you will have the classes for compilation, but the jars will not be added to your war file. Then there will be only the version in the tomcat lib directory and it will work.